# Clustering Words

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis

I have a list of words. I am looking for a way to cluster these words together semantically. Can anyone tell me about a library or tool that accomplishes this? I have been searching this on net a lot but nothing suits my requirements. Most of the words are technical and so won't be found in any dictionary. I want to perform ontological clustering on the list of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a collection so you will have a context to work with?

If you ha a given collection you can use you can compute the number of documents each pair of terms appear together and, based on that calculate some semantic similarity between them like 
[Jaccard] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) or [Dice] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice%27s_coefficient).

Comment: thanks for the idea.....can you guide me as to which type of clustering will suit my purposes best here?

Comment: [K-means] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) should be a good point to start

Comment: The problem is called:

Frequent itemset mining. And you can find info on the Ullman book "Mining of Massive Datasets".